# How to have two-column registration form in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have two-column registration form using bootstrap 3, other pages of my website are fine except the registration page. My input fields and labels scattered all over the screen on the right side because I am using `col-md-6` for to divide the page into two. The page looks like this now.

[image]

As you can see, the right side is idk, they are scattered. How to fix this side? My code is something like this in both sides:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- start code on the left side of the page -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><font color="red"><b>*</b></font> First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" 
                        placeholder="Firstname" onKeyPress="return ValidateAlpha(event);" onblur="toUpper(this.value, this.id);"/>        
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- left code ends here -->

        <!-- start code on the right side of the page -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><font color="red"><b>*</b></font> E-mail</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder= "email" 
                            ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" /></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right code ends here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code required to reproduce the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: clear:both should solve your issue. But if you can post full code on jsfiddle, we can try to help you.

Comment: i tried before publishing this question, but it doesn't show the same output on jsfiddle because it's bootstrap. but anyway, here's  the https://jsfiddle.net/uzjm719b/ @shoeb

Comment: You are using very bad html. Let me fix it for you..

Comment: thank you! would mean a lot sir!!! @shoeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the codepen I've made for you 
http://codepen.io/creativemind1/pen/QNYqqN

Kindly remove the `!important` from the css and make changes in your style.css

**EDIT:** You are not suppose to give any classes in label and `<div class="col-md-6">` before input as it will automatically align for you.

Comment: omg you are the best!!!!! Thank you so so much! I would vote for this a hundred times if I could!!! Thank you thank you thank you sir!!!!

Comment: And thanks for the advice! Big thanks to you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Try `clearfix` class in bootstrap.

Codepen example http://codepen.io/smallyin/pen/vGbegv

Comment: it did work, it is no longer like before. but how will i have the same spaces like i had on my left side of the page? because after `email` is `username` and it has no spaces on between. they are like attached to each other even though `username` is on the next line already. i'm sorry i'm not good at explaining but i hope u got my point.